# iphone Data Matrix BarCode

Tags: objective-c

Anyone can give any idea or suggestion regarding Data matrix barcode reader?

I used the Zbar but it supports the QR but not supporting the DataMatrix.Can u please suggest with any other source code available for free to read Data Matrix barcode reader. ##

Is there a framework or other sample code for doing Data matrix barcode recognition on iPhone / iPad?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/Barcode
This is a working sample but other than real time detection,it requires to take a snapshot of the barcode and sometimes it is unable to decode.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But i have used this code ,it contain lots of drawbacks.